# How can I compare a set to an array in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get all unique URLs on a web page e.g. https://www.ig.com/uk/trading-strategies (there can be duplicates) and then compare them to URLs in an array and if the URLs are unique to write data to a Google Sheet.

I'm really struggling getting all the unique URLs on a webpage e.g. https://www.ig.com/uk/trading-strategies. I thought I could append unique URLs to a list then to a set and then to a tuple to compare against the array but that doesn't seem to be working.

Do you have any insights that could help?

Thanks in advance

Mark

```
obj = {r[2]: True for r in sh.get_all_values()}
ar = []

articles = set()
unique = (articles)

for url in urls:
    my_url = requests.get(url)
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for item in soup.find_all("h3", class_="article-category-section-title"):
        date = datetime.date.today()
        title = item.find("a", class_="primary js_target").text.strip()
        article = item.find("a", class_="primary js_target").get("href")
        abs = "https://www.ig.com"
        rel = article
        pub = rel[-6:]
        datestring = f"{pub[4:6]} {pub[2:4]} {pub[0:2]}"
        info = {"date": date, "title": title, "url":urllib.parse.urljoin(abs, rel), "published":datestring}
        article = str(info["url"].replace("https://",""))
        articles.add(article)
        if unique not in obj:
            ar.append([str(info["date"]), str(info["title"]), article, str(info["published"])])
if ar != []:
    sh.append_rows(ar, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

Comment: What's `unique = str(articles)` supposed to do?  `unique` is just a `'set()'` (a string).  It's unlikely to be found in `obj`, whatever `obj` might be.

Comment: Also, is the question about `beautifulsoup` or comparing sets to lists?

Comment: Hey i just update my code and removed the string. I wanted unique to hold the contents of the set. I already did the beautiful soup part to get the data so its about comparing sets to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought I could append unique URLs to a list then to a set and then to a tuple to compare against the array but that doesn't seem to be working.

Instead, you could just only add URLs that haven't been added already by adding maintaining and checking against a list of URLs that *have* been added already. Try

```py
prev_links = [r[2] for r in sh.get_all_values()]
ar = []

# (I prefer to define constants outside loop) 
abs_url = "https://www.ig.com" 
h_selector = 'h3[class="article-category-section-title"]'
link_selector = f'{h_selector} a[class="primary js_target"][href]'

for url in urls:
    my_url = requests.get(url)
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    date_today = str(datetime.date.today())
    for arLink in soup.select(link_selector):
        rel_url = arLink.get("href")
        full_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(abs_url, rel_url)
        article = str(full_url.replace("https://",""))
        if article in prev_links: 
            continue # skip if already added

        title = arLink.text.strip()
        pub_date = rel_url[-6:]
        pub_date = f"{pub_date[4:6]} {pub_date[2:4]} {pub_date[0:2]}"

        ar.append([date_today, title, article, pub_date]) # no need for str() - they're all strings already
        prev_links.append(article) # maintain list of already-added-urls

if ar != []:
    sh.append_rows(ar, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```